# online private source control system

Tags: version-control

I am looking for a *private* online source control system. Basically what I want is a private version of [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) or [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/). Private in the sense that only me and the person I invite can view the source code. The source code in the source control should not be exposed to search engines or other people without the proper viewing rights.

I prefer to hold the source code on other servers, not on my machine. I don't want to handle all the database maintenance and backup and things like that. In exchange for this I don't mind to pay a monthly access fee for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Atlassian's BitBucket just announced Git repositories last week. Bit bucket allows unlimited private repositories for free. You need to pay if you want more than 5 users.

Answer (score 17):

A vote here for [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/)

The free offering has 200mb and unlimited (numbers of) git/svn repositories within that 200mb.

Comment: Looks like the free option is gone now :(

Answer (score 10):

Assembla - for Subversion - [www.assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com).  Free Subversion / Trac

Comment: Assembla now supports DVSCs: Git & Mercurial

Comment: is not free anymore. Just for students is free

Comment: @Duncan, now it's back to free!!

Answer (score 8):

A friend of mine recently told me about [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) by [ATLASSIAN](http://www.atlassian.com/software/development-tools.jsp)

This is a great one, including their free plan version.

Answer (score 4):

[GitHub](http://github.com/) can do that (with a paid-for account).

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been posted a while ago. But, how about this:

If you're developing from a Windows machine, download the Google Drive client and sync your Google Driver folders on your local machine. Within those synced folders, create one called repository or something.

Then using git, you create a bare repository in that folder. Or in Bazaar, a repository with no-trees. This will create a repository that will not contain the actual working files, but just keep the revision history. This has the advantage of saving disk space as well as letting you pull and push from/to it like a centralized repo.

And since it is within your Google Drive synchronized folders, it will be backed up on Google drive and synced. And you can allow access to your folders using email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

For Subversion I use [DevjaVu](http://www.devjavu.com/).