# What are the free alternatives to Google Code (project hosting)?

Tags: google-code, svn-repository

I'm using Google Code to host some of my hobby projects. I want to make some of my code private, and unfortunately you can't do this on the Google Code site.

I was looking at Project Kenai but I've read some rumours that Oracle are pulling the plug on that.

What free alternatives are there, which give an SVN repository (although I'm open to alternatives) that will allow me to checkin my code somewhere, but to also allow me to keep some (or all) of it private, ie require authentication to checkout/view

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216349/online-private-source-control-system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Codeplex.com as well. I think it let's you create private projects and offer SVN and Mercurial repos.

Answer (score 3):

you can use www.assembla.com . You can also create a git repository in assembla . Private as well as public repository are supported.

Comment: @brimborium I am using assembla. It was free until yesterday . Did they change something today ??

Comment: I just went to their [page](https://www.assembla.com/home) and found out that they actually have a free version with some restrictions. So it is still free. Sorry about the confusing. I heard rumors and did check, but obviously not good enough. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've always considered [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) to be very good.  They have a free trial account.